# Katalon add authorization header fails

Tags: groovy, http-headers, katalon-studio

I'm trying to put authorization header by code on my web request.
The authorization value is obtained by the login response.

Here's how I create the login request:

```
loginResponse = WS.sendRequest(loginRequest)
WS.verifyResponseStatusCode(loginResponse, 200)
println '>>> login status code is: ' + loginResponse.statusCode
```

and getting the response like this:

```
println '>>> response: ' + loginResponse.getResponseBodyContent()
String responseString = loginResponse.getResponseBodyContent()
JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper()
Map responseParsed = slurper.parseText(responseString)
println '>>> token: ' + responseParsed.token
```

Next, I want to hit another endpoint, using header as Authorization with value from `responseParsed.token`. It looks like this:

```
RequestObject requestActivate = new RequestObject('activator')
TestObjectProperty propToken = new TestObjectProperty('Authorization', ConditionType.EQUALS, responseParsed.token)
ArrayList headers = Arrays.asList(propToken)
requestActivate.setHttpHeaderProperties(headers)
requestActivate.setRestUrl('http://xxxxxx.com/registration/activate_email')
requestActivate.setRestRequestMethod('GET')
verifResponse = WS.sendRequest(findTestObject('Object Repository/REST_Cicil/Hit Email Verification API - Staging Main'))
```

but I always get the `403 Forbidden` error. It looks as if I didn't add the header properly. I've tried to hit it manually using Postman and it works.

Comment: What is the type of `responseParsed.token` when defining `propToken`? Try using `responseParsed.token.toString()`.

Comment: @MateMrše responseParsed is Map as shown above, and i put the token directly.. i've used the responseParsed.token.toString() too btw with same result

Comment: Can you show `findTestObject('Object Repository/REST_Cicil/Hit Email Verification API - Staging Main')`?

Answer (score 2):

except only authorization, try to add content-type and accept to be full header.

for example :

```
String endpoint = "https://www.katalon.com"
 String requestMethod = "GET"
 String authHeader = "whateverYouNeedForAuthentication"
 TestObjectProperty header1 = new TestObjectProperty("Authorization", ConditionType.EQUALS, authHeader)
 TestObjectProperty header2 = new TestObjectProperty("Content-Type", ConditionType.EQUALS, "application/json")
 TestObjectProperty header3 = new TestObjectProperty("Accept", ConditionType.EQUALS, "application/json")
 ArrayList defaultHeaders = Arrays.asList(header1, header2, header3)


public ResponseObject buildApiRequest1() {
  RequestObject ro = new RequestObject("objectId")
  ro.setRestUrl(endpoint)
  ro.setHttpHeaderProperties(defaultHeaders)
  ro.setRestRequestMethod(requestMethod)
  ResponseObject respObj = WS.sendRequest(ro)
  return respObj
 }
```

[Reference Link](https://dzone.com/articles/create-rest-api-request-manually-using-katalon-stu)